# repeated measures design between subjects with non normal and small N

Tags: normal-distribution, repeated-measures, nonparametric, small-sample

I’m examining the effects of a parent-delivered reading intervention on 11 child outcome variables at 3 different time points (pre, post-intervention and follow-up) with a control group. Total sample size is 20. At pre test, all 20 participants completed the measures. At post testing, I have missing data for two variables and at follow-up, there is complete data for only 18 participants (9 for each group). I was planning to do a repeated measure ANOVA to examine performance over time, group mean differences and possible interaction effects.
I examined descriptive data for each variable by group and ran Shapiro Wilk tests to determine if the data for each variable meets the assumption of approximation of a normal distribution. Based on these results, 6 of my variables (with P values less than .05) do not meet the assumption (on at least 1 point in time).

I have a few questions as to how to analyze my data.

1. Given that not all my variables meet the normality assumption for running parametric analysis, would it be appropriate to transform my variables?

2.If yes, what would be an appropriate transformation technique to use with SPSS?

1. If I’m having to transform almost half of my data, would it be better to select  anon-parametric analysis?
2. If yes, should I use Friedman's two-way analysis for the repeated measure analysis (within) and a Mann-Whitney for the between measure analysis?
3. Is there a non-parametric test that can test interaction effects?
4. Lastly, if I use non-parametric analysis, would I be able to calculate effect sizes.

Comment: The data do not have to be normal to run ANOVA, the residuals do. However, for RM ANOVA, there is a requirement of sphericity which is unlikely to be met. I suggest a multilevel model or a GEE model.

Comment: @PeterFlom pardon my ignorance, but what does GEE stand for?

Comment: Generalized estimating equation